# Integral representation of the Digamma function vs. Integral representation of the Polygamma function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Yesterday I asked for the derivation of the Integral representation of the Digamma-Function:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113119/integral-representation-of-digamma-function

Thanks again @Jair Taylor for the great and detailed explanation.

Today, however, I stumbled across the Integral representation of the Polygamma-Function on Wikipedia:

$\psi^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {t^{n}e^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt$

For $n=0$ this should represent an Integral representation for the Digamma-Function. So if I insert $n=0$ into the equation I end up with:

$\psi^{(0)}(x)=(-1)\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {e^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt$

This, however, is different from the Integral representation of the Digamma-Function I ended up with yesterday:

$\psi (x)=\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {e^{-t}}{t}}-{\frac {e^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt$

So how is it possible that the two Integral representation differ by the factor $\frac {e^{-t}}{t}$ within the Integral and still both are correct?

Please apologize if the solution is kind of obvious, I thought a lot about it and still don't see it.

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: it is all explained in the last small paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Integral_representation. :)

Comment: Yeah,

I'm so sorry, sorry for the stupid question...

Answer (score 2):

I tried $x=1$.
I get
$$
\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {e^{-t}}{t}}-{\frac {e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt
= -\gamma = \psi(1)
$$
and
$$
(-1)\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt 
 = -\infty \ne \psi(1)
$$
even though Maple erroneously gets $-\gamma$ for this one also.  The integral clearly diverges, since the integrand behaves like $1/t$ near $t=0$.

Where did you get $\psi^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {t^{n}e^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt$ ?  Did it perhaps state $n > 0$ as a condition?

Comment: yes, the condition $n>0$ is stated, for example, in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Integral_representation)

Comment: Yeah,

I'm so sorry, I somehow overread the $n>0$. Sorry for the stupid question...